# Parse SDK cross compile Intel Edison

Tags: parse-platform, intel, iot, intel-edison

I'm trying to figure out how to configure Eclipse (on a Mac) to cross compile for Parse running on an Intel Edison.

I can do the steps and natively compile on the Edison but I'm can't figure out how to find the binary libparse to link with on the Mac for a cross compile.

Answer (score 0):

Well, I figured it out.
For the next travelers, here's what I did:

- Download all the tools and build parse SDK on your Edison
- Put an SD card in the reader and copy libparse.0.0.0 (or whatever is the latest version) to the SD card (/media/sdcard).  You'll find it in /usr/lib
- Execute the shutdown command
- Wait for Linux to shutdown (see serial terminal)
- Put SD card in Mac
- Copy libparse.o.0.0.0 to wherever you’ve installed the iotdk-ide-mac from Intel.  Mine was in a "dev" directory under my Mac user.

  - /Users/xxx/dev/iotdk-ide-mac/devkit-x86/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/lib
- Make a copy and rename it libparse.o
- In Eclipse, add “parse” (w/o quotes) as a library under project properties, linker setttings
- Download the parse embedded SDK and expand it.
- Copy parse.h from the include directory in the embedded sdks and put it in /Users/xxx/dev/iotdk-ide-mac/devkit-x86/sysroots/i586-poky-linux/usr/include